# How do I know what key/value and the proper syntax of my router.yaml file in symfony?

Tags: symfony

I am just learning symphony please bear with me. I do not want to blindly copy and paste stuff without a real meaning.

In routes.yaml i am seing string such as this :

```
route1:
    path:     /foo
    defaults: { _controller: 'MyController::fooAction' }
```

why does "_controller" use the underscore? how would i know that it need the underscore without saying : "that is just the way to use it" ? 
why are they using :: to refer to a function method that is not a static method? 
How do i get a list of all the keys/value syntax for that that router file? 
where do i get the hierarchy of the key/value pair of the yaml file?

In other places i am seeing string like this:

```
app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

This one looks cleaner but where is the underscore in word "controller"?

**Why so many inconsistencies?**

BTW: I have read this: BTW: I read this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html#defining-routes
it is stated that a full route has seven parts but how do i know the proper syntax of those parts?

Any insights will be appreciated...

Thanks.

Comment: Most of your questions are answered in the framework (as opposed to component) [routing documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) The syntax in your second example (controller vs _controller) was recently introduced in Symfony 4.  There are other changes on Symfony 4 as well so whenever your read something you need to verify that it applies to your Symfony version.

Comment: @Cerad. The problem was that they both work and backward compatible and i was not aware that one was from the previous version. I will pay attention to that moving forward. Thanks.